# Is my code legal in Android usage?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

I asked a question recently about how to disable the back button is Android, after a while I got it working with these lines of code

```
public override void OnBackPressed ()
    {
       //  base.OnBackPressed ();            /*  Comment this base call to avoid calling Finish()  */
       //  Do nothing
    }
```

And just recently someone commented this

> Disabling the back button is counter-intuitive and breaks the device
>   usage contract imposed by Android. So i suggest you rethink.

-Question-
What would be a possible change to this? I dont want to be able to press the back button when playing my quiz game because that would make be able to cheat. New to android Development

Comment: I don´t think the one who has answered is wright.  Like described in the API: Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity, but you can override this to do whatever you want.

Comment: "but you can override this to do whatever you want" suggests me that I can simply override it without hurting any android developer guidelines....

Comment: I think I understand, The user can end the app with the click of the home button its just that the user cantgo back or close the application with the back button once the quiz has started
https://gyazo.com/e13a27bcc5902bf176b876fe8ac08bd8 Here is how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of simply making the back button do nothing, you could have it create a popup asking something along the lines of "Are you sure you want to leave the quiz? (This will count as a loss)". And have it take the user back to the main page of your app if he confirms (instead of back to the previous page).

Comment: I will try that! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not imitate what many websites do and make it so going 'back' to a page works but doesn't display any information?

It depends on your code, but perhaps you can make your buttons and text (or whatever it is you don't want them interacting with) change to be unseen whenever they move on to a new page. Or just throw up a message that says 'You can't do that' to cover the page that they'll only ever see if they go back to view it again.

Comment: I think I will simply make it end the application if the user presses the back button and then it restarts when the user opens it. Not sure if Finish(); will solve it but I will try!